# Calculate Rate per hour based on Time

Tags: java, jsp

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Rate_Per_Hour {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String TimeStart = "09.30.00 am";
        String TimeEnd= "10.10.00 am";

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss a");
        int total=0;
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;

        try {
            d1 = format.parse(TimeStart);
            d2 = format.parse(TimeEnd);

            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;

            if (diffMinutes <= 30) {
               total = 20;
            } 
            else if (diffHours <=1){
               total = 35;
            } 

            System.out.println("Rs." +total);
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want output like this:
(Fixed rate per hour for this is Rs.35 )

For 30 min = Rs.20

For 40 min = Rs.25 and so on......

For 1 hour = Rs.35

For 1 hour 10 min = Rs.40

Please help me, figure out how I can do this.

Comment: What are the outputs you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Since the rate increases by 5 every 10 minutes, so just use a simple function to return the rate:

```
public double rate(int minutes) 
{ 
return 20 + 5*((minutes - 30)/10);
}
```

Calculate the number of minutes and then pass it as an argument in that function to get the rate. Also, try to keep your code as short as possible but at the same time, simple.

Comment: Or just `5 + minutes / 2`

Comment: Yeah, pretty much the same thing.

Comment: thank you all,but after 1 hour 30 min  it would be  gives Rs.50 instead of Rs.55

Comment: Every 10 mins rate increases by 5 so after 1 hr 30 mins it would be 50 not 55.

Answer (score 0):

if you need something more flexible rather than fixed rate you could implement an `enum` with predefined stops

you could define any rate you want for a given time.
for example if long running tasks shall gain higher rates (from your question it was not obvious to me if this rate shall be just the calculated value as in Manish Kundu's answer or if other values might get assigned.)

with this code you could assign higher rates for long running `jobs` (for example in computer games, jobs that are harder to achieve you return a higher rate or you lower the rate because the player took too much time...)

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class TimeMain {
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh.mm.ss[ ]a");

public enum Rate {
    STOP0(0, 0, 0), // default
    STOP1(0, 30, 20), // 30 mins -> Rs.20
    STOP2(0, 40, 25), // 40 mins -> Rs.25
    STOP3(1, 0, 35), // 1 hour -> Rs.35
    STOP4(1, 10, 40); // 1 hour 10 minutes -> Rs.40

    int minutes = 0;
    int rate = 0;

    /*
     * hours is actually not needed as 1h10 = 70mins...
     */
    private Rate(int hours, int minutes, int rate) {
        this.minutes = minutes + hours * 60;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public static Rate from(String timeStart, String timeEnd) {
        LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse(timeStart.toUpperCase(), dateTimeFormatter);
        LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse(timeEnd.toUpperCase(), dateTimeFormatter);
        long minutesBetween = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(time1, time2);
        for (int i = 0; i < Rate.values().length; i++) {
            Rate r = Rate.values()[i];
            if (r.minutes > minutesBetween) {
                return Rate.values()[i-1];
            }
        }
        return STOP0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Rs.%s", rate);
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    String timeStart = "09.30.00 am";
    String timeEnd = "10.10.00 am";

    System.out.println(Rate.from(timeStart, timeEnd));
}
```

}